# Java throwing exception on Play bindFromRequest

Tags: java, binding, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to bind some data from a `POST`, but for some reason, it keeps throwing an exception. The weird thing though is that I have an almost identical object that is bound just fine. Some of my code is as follows:

```
public static Result login() {
return ok(
  login.render(Form.form(Login.class))
);
}


public static Result authenticate() {
  Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
  // Do stuff
}

public static Result createUser() {
        return ok(createUser.render(Form.form(NewUser.class)));
}

public static Result createUserPost() {
        Form<NewUser> newUserForm = Form.form(NewUser.class).bindFromRequest();
        // Do stuff
}

public static class Login {
  public String userName;
  public String password;
  public String validate(){
    Logger.info("userName: %s, Password: %s", userName, password);
    if (User.validate(userName, password) == null){
      return "Invalid username or password";
    }
    return null;
  }
}

public static class NewUser {
        public String userName;
        public String password;

        public String validate() {
                // TODO: Better error messages
                if (Validation.username(userName) == null && Validation.password(password) == null) {
                        return null;
                }
                else {
                        return "The username or password is not valid.";
                }
        }
}
```

For some reason, the `authenticate` method binds the `Login` class fine, but the `createUserPost` method doesn't bind the `NewUser` class (both views are exactly the same with the exception that the Form type is either `Login` or `NewUser`). The weirder thing is that if I change the `createUser`, `createUserPost`, and the view to use the `Login` class, it binds just fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that for some reason Play (or Java) doesn't like having multiple static classes in the same Java file. Once we refactored the two classes out to their own files, it worked fine.